# Adding checkbox controls to list box

Tags: c#, listbox, listbox-control

I'm new to .NET environment and just a student.
I'm working on User Management. I want to assign multiple roles to one user. For this purpose I've created  list box which contains a list of roles from database.

```
 lbRoles.Items.Add(readerRole["RoleName"].ToString());
```

I just need a check box with each item. Please suggest how to add a checkbox with each item.
I did tried

```
lbRoles.Controls.Add(checkBox);
lbRoles.Items.Add(readerRole["RoleName"].ToString());
```

But it was not helpful. I did google but no result :(

Comment: while "checkBox" is an object of class CheckBox in this code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is the [CheckedListBox class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), its very simple and does exactly what you want. :)

*Displays a ListBox in which a check box is displayed to the left of each item.*

Comment: Databinding a CheckedListBox can be problematic.

Comment: @beanmf You could always use a datagridview (which easily supports data binding) and add a checkbox column if your data source doesn't already have a boolean column.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using a ListBox, use a ListView instead and set [ListView.Checkboxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.checkboxes%28VS.80%29.aspx)  to true.

This will place a CheckBox next to each item in the ListView, and your users can select specific items in the ListView by clicking the checkboxes, then get the selected items using [ListView.SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: and ListViews don't support DataBinding at all

Comment: At this time, you must use ListView.CheckedItems instead of ListView.SelectedItems.